# Make buffer of cv mat Point to the buffer of QImage

Tags: qt, opencv

I would like to make the buffer of cv::mat point to the buffer of QImage but not copy
the data of QImage into the cv::mat.

```
cv::Mat const reference_qimage_to_mat(QImage const &img, int format)
{
    cv::Mat mat(img.height(), img.width(), format);

    for(int i = 0; i != mat.rows; ++i)
    {
        //pseudo code, wouldn't work
        //mat.ptr(i) = img.scanLine(i);
    }

    return mat;
}
```

I try to search the answer by google but I could only find how to copy
the data of QImage into cv::mat.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `cv::Mat` object is simply a header for the image data, so you can do it upon your object construction:

```
cv::Mat mat(img.height(), img.width(), type, img.bits());
```

where `type` depends on your data, `CV_8UC1` for single channel, `CV_8UC3` for RGB, etc.

Comment: Note opencv internally expects data as BGR

Comment: Thanks, this solution is easy and clean

Comment: I do some test, looks like it wouldn't delete the buffer.char *raw = new char[100];
    *raw = 'a';

    {
        cv::Mat mat(10, 10, CV_8U, raw);
    }

    qDebug() << *raw;This is the behaviour I want